# increment a number in java until it gets to 100 than decrement down to 0 continously

Tags: java, increment

I'm making a game where there is a goalie. i want him to move back and forth forever. i have an int called goalieposx (goalie position on the x axis) and i want this is go up by 1 until it hits 200, then go down by one till its back a 0 and repeat. I've tried the folllowing

```
//this bit isnt in the method, its outside as global varibale
boolean forward=true

//this bit is in a method which is continiouly called nonstop
if (goalieposx<200){
        forward=true;
    }
    else if (goalieposx>200){
        forward=false;
    }
    System.out.println(forward);

    if(forward=true){
        goalieposx++;
        System.out.println("forward");
    }
    else if (forward=false){
        goalieposx--;
        System.out.println("backwards");
    }

}
```

this method is called continously. It prints true until it gets to 200, then it prints false. However, it always prints forward, never backward. So conclusion is: the boolean changes as expected but the first if is always called, it seems to ignore the condition

ive also tried this

```
           if(forward = true){
        if(goalieposx==200){

            forward=false;

        }
        else{
        goalieposx++;}
    }
    else{
        if(goalieposx==0){
            forward=true;
        }
        else{
        goalieposx--;}
             System.out.println(goalieposx);
    }
```

but this doesnt work either, it prints 1 then 2 etc upto 200 then prints 200 forever. Anyone know how i can solve this? is an if statement the wrong idea altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why you should never do comparison for `boolean` types in `if`, `while`, `for`, whatever. You have just done the assignment in your `if` statement:

```
if(forward=true)
```

the above `if` statement will always evaluate to `true`. The problem with this is, this compiles successfully in `Java`, as syntax wise it's alright. Compiler just checks the type of expression in `if` evaluates to `boolean` or not. And it does, so it's ok with it.

You need to do the comparison:

```
if(forward==true)
```

.. but as I said, you should not do comparison for `boolean` types. So, simply doing this:

```
if(forward)
```

would be enough.

---

You also don't need those `else if` in both the conditions. Just an `else` will work fine. Well, I don't understand the use of `boolean` variable at all. It seems like you don't need it. You can change your code to:

```
if (goalieposx<200){
    // forward=true;
    goalieposx++;
    System.out.println("forward");
}
else {
    // forward=false; 
    goalieposx--;
    System.out.println("backwards");
}
```

What you were previously doing is, setting a `boolean` variable, based on a condition, and using that `boolean` variable as condition to execute another `if-else` block. Well, whatever you are executing in the 2nd `if-else` block, can simply be moved in the original `if-else` block, without taking the help of the middle-actor `boolean` variable.

Comment: OMG i cannot believe that. Thanks so much i've been trying to get this working for almost 2 hours! OMG

Comment: oh yeah, i used else if as a test for something else and forgot to remove it. Thanks though

Comment: +1 for good explanation. @user2762277 this is a really basic concept, I suggest picking up an introduction to Java text and reading for a bit before you jump into coding too much as you're going to spend a lot of time spinning your wheels if you don't know the really basic stuff.

Answer (score 2):

`if(forward=true)` **does not do what you thing it does**.

In java `=` is the assignment operator and `==` is the comparison operator. What you are doing with that statement is saying "if assign `forward` to `true`" which will set `forward` to `true` and always `return true`.

What you mean to say is `if(forward)` and `if(!forward)`.

In fact you don't need the `else if` just an `else` as if the `boolean` is not `true` it must be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it is to get it to move to the left by adding a minus number, and to the right by adding a positive number. Here's an example of doing this with a loop:

```
    for(int i = -10; i < 100; i++) {
        xPosition += i;
    }
```

This would add -10 then -9 etc. to the position.

Comment: This doesn't seem better. Are you thinking of a sine-like function?

Comment: There's a lot less code, plus it's easy to read. That's why it's better.

Comment: Those are improvements, but it only turns around once, and doesn't go from 0 to 200.

Comment: This was just an example and is easily adaptable. The OP doesn't need spoon-feeding.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statements, you need to put two equal signs to check for equality.

```
if (forward == true){
    // execute code
}
```

EDIT 1:

```
if (forward)
```

would be much simpler.

Comment: And not `if(forward)`. Why not `if(forward == (1 == 1))` then?

Comment: @BoristheSpider What about - `if ((forward == true) == true)`?

Answer (score 0):

First let's examine what you have already written:

```
if (goalieposx<200){
    forward=true;
}
else if (goalieposx>200){
    forward=false;
}
```

The problem with this code being first is that it while it might set the direction to false once 'goalieposx' has reached 201, in the next call, it will set the direction back to true.

Instead, try using this clever alternative:

```
//This goes before the infinite loop method
counter = 0;

//Then in the infinite loop method
counter++;
if(counter > 100) {
   counter = -100;
}
goalieposx = 100 + counter; //(this shifts counter from
                            // between -100 and 100 to 0 and 200)
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are setting the direction based on the value of the integer, instead of whether a condition has previously been met.  Try this:

```
//this bit is in a method which is continiouly called nonstop
    if (forward && (goalieposx>200)){
        forward=false;
    }

    System.out.println(forward);

    if(forward=true){
        goalieposx++;
        System.out.println("forward");
    }
    else if (forward=false){
        goalieposx--;
        System.out.println("backwards");
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't the problem at all.